# Best way to get the context of an activity in a viewmodel

Tags: android, android-context, dagger-hilt

I want to use this context to make a notification, but it should be called in a viewmodel that is made by `hiltViewModel()` function. How should I pass the context there?

Comment: It's not a good practice keep the activity's context in a view model since the view model has a longer lifecycle than an activity, so it might cause memory leaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend creating a single method that accepts a context and displays the notification. This way you'll avoid memory leaks which can be caused if you store the activity's context instead.